# Can't open downloaded file using filesaver.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, filesaver.js

Error : PowerPoint found a problem with content in abc.pptx Cannot open the file, the file may be damaged.

Client side code (using filesaver.js to save file)

```
$http.get(url)
    .then(function(resp) {
      var file = new Blob([resp.data], {type : 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml‌​.presentation'});
      saveAs(file, "abc.pptx");
    }, function(error) {
       return $q.reject(error.data.message);
    });
```

Server side code

```
app.get('/..', function (req, res) {
  stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
  stream.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Can you try adding the MIME type to the Blob options? `application/vnd.ms-powerpoint`

Comment: @Phix I tried application/vnd.ms-powerpoint & 
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation but both didn't worked.